# How do we know how an angle is defined?

Tags: geometry

Take the angle PQR.  Below it's labeled 45 degrees.

How do we know PQR is 45 degrees and not 315 degrees (the reflexive angle)?  And I know it says "45 degrees", but what if it said 'X'.  Then how do we know PQR isn't '360-X' degrees?

[image]

Comment: I’ll let someone more knowledgeable leave an official answer, but I believe it’s the convention that we take the angle less than or equal to $180^\circ$.

Comment: Generally, if they wanted to indicate the larger angle, the green sector would go all around the angle, as opposed to what it is doing there.

Comment: The green arc shows the angle in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angle $\angle PQR$ is measured by starting at the ray $\overrightarrow{QP}$ and then rotating that ray counterclockwise until we end up at the ray $\overrightarrow{QR}$. The direction matters. $\angle PQR$ and $\angle RQP$ are generally not the same. In fact, you measured the angle the wrong way round. In your example, the angle you drew is $\angle RQP$, not $\angle PQR$, and $\angle PQR$ would be $315^\circ$, not $45^\circ$.

Comment: Do you have a reference that you could point out to me? I’ve always just used the convention that it is the lesser of the two angles.

Comment: @Clayton To be a bit more precise, there are multiple conventions. Some using directed angles (as I did), some using undirected angles (as Sammy Black did). Both can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle#Identifying_angles
To me, the directed angle convention has a more "mathematical" feel, while the undirected one feels more "engineery". One comes with an additional discontinuity, which isn't "nice" from a math pov. But the other one measures a more physically significant thing (two iron rods with a $45^\circ$ or $315^\circ$ angle between them are physically the same thing).

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: we don't unless there's more information!

One convention that might be assumed in the context of the work you're doing is that an angle is the *smallest positive* angle between the rays $\vec{QR}$ and $\vec{QP}$, in which case it's $\frac{\pi}{4} = 45^\circ$.

Or perhaps the placement of the label on the diagram indicates the intended angle.

---

By the way, if you're looking for a *definition* of an angle, you have to draw in a circular arc with center at the vertex $Q$. Then the angle is defined as the ratio of the length of the arc to the radius of the circle:
$$
\theta = \frac{s}{r},
$$
which simplifies to $\theta = s$ if you draw the circular arc with radius $r=1$. This is of course, the *natural* unit**less** way to measure angle. If you insist on dividing a circle up into the (arbitrary) number of $360$ equal pieces then you have to convert:
$$
\theta^\circ = \theta \cdot \frac{360^\circ}{2\pi}.
$$